# Функция sort и алгоритмы сортировки

Tags: c++, алгоритм, сортировка

Скорее всего, все наслышаны про различные алгоритмы сортировок. Также, в C++ есть встроенная библиотека `<algorithm>`, в которой есть функция `sort`. Использовать ли её, и будет ли это быстрее, чем алгоритмы сортировок?

Comment: Всё зависит от того, какие именно данные сортируются и в каком количестве

Comment: Чтобы узнать, что быстрее, померяйте время. Что-то мне подсказывает, что обогнать будет сложно (ведь у разработчиков крупных компиляторов были годы на оптимизацию стандартных алгоритмов), если только речь не идет об каком-то отдельном узком случае, под который ваш алгоритм спецаильно приспособлен (как пример, загляните [сюда](https://www.toptal.com/developers/sorting-algorithms): insertion sort иногда обгоняет более продвинутые алгоритмы на почти отсортированных массивах, хотя обычно он медленнее).

Comment: Но вообще, вы бы лучше не занимались написанием велосипедов. Вот если у вас программа начнет тормозить из-за сортировки, и если вы не сможете нагуглить более быстрые алгоритмы, тогда можно будет пробовать.

Comment: `Использовать ли её, и будет ли это быстрее, чем алгоритмы сортировок?` - использовать готовое всегда быстрее, чем писать что-то свое.

Answer (score 1):

std::sort реализует один из алгоритмов сортировки (а иначе как отсортировать, если не использовать алгоритм сортировки).

Поэтому, правильно вопрос должен звучать где то так - алгоритм сортировки в std::sort хорош или нет? И ответ будет такой - в общем случае алгоритм std::sort достаточно хорош. Он обесчечивает n*ln(n) сложность.

Но очень часто нам известны некоторые характеристики сортируемого массива. И в этом случае самопальные алгоритмы могут оказаться сильно-сильно быстрее. К примеру, если массив уже почти отсортирован (всего 1-2 элемента не на своем месте) - в этом случае хорошо отработает обычный пузырек. Или массив состоит из однобайтовых чисел. В этом случае хорошо отработает сортировка подсчетом (за ленейное время).

И ещё один момент - сортировки бывают устойчивые и нет. Устойчивые сортировки сохранят относительный порядок одинаковых элементов. Если сортировать числа, то разницы нет, а вот если сложные объекты, то это может быть очень важно. std::sort реализует неустойчивую сортировку. А для устойчивой можно использовать `stable_sort`.

И последний момент - разные сортировки используют разный объем памяти. Пузырьку нужно всего два счетчика и одна переменная для обмена (но часто можно и без нее). А некоторым сортировкам нужны двукратные запасы. И если массив достаточно большой, то "быстрая сортировка" может быть не такой быстрой (память не безгранична, а своп - медленный). А пузырек потихоньку может и обогнать.

Comment: Судя по разнице в описании требований к памяти для [sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) и [stable_sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/stable_sort/) рискну предположить, что *`sort`* использует `quicksort`, а *`stable_sort`* в основном варианте это `timsort` (а когда памяти мало -- [In-place mergesort](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.22.5514&rep=rep1&type=pdf) (или нечто подобное))

Answer (score 0):

Библиотека C++ содержит целый ряд альгоритмов сортировки:

```
is_sorted  (C++11)
```

проверяет, является ли диапазон отсортированым в порядке возрастания

```
is_sorted_until  (C++11)
```

находит наибольший из отсортированых поддиапазонов

```
sort
```

сортирует диапазон в порядке возрастания

```
partial_sort
```

сортирует первые N элементов в диапазоне

```
partial_sort_copy
```

копирует и частично сортирует диапазон элементов

```
stable_sort
```

сортирует диапазон элементов при сохранении порядка между равными элементами

```
nth_element
```

помещает n-й элемент в позицию, которую он занимал бы после сортировки всего диапазона

В зависимости от задачи используйте один из этих альгоритмов. Все они работают максимально быстро, если правильно выбрать. Хотя могут быть случаи, когда простой альгоритм, написанным для конкретного тривиального случая, может оказаться быстрее...

Comment: `Библиотека C++ содержит целый ряд алгоритмов сортировки: is_sorted ...` - `is_sorted` - это не алгоритм сортировки, а просто функция, проверяющая, отсортирован ли массив. Из перечисленного только 4 функции выполняют сортировку.

Comment: @insolor, 7 - 2 == 5, а не 4. Во вторых проверка  косвенно является тоже сортировкой. Т.е. если последовательность сортирован, то его не нужно сортировать

Comment: Ок, пусть будет 5, хотя последнее тоже не сортировка, хотя внутри вызывает функцию сортировки. И нет, проверка не является сортировкой. И еще одно: `sort`, `partial_sort`, `partial_sort_copy` скорее всего используют один и тот же алгоритм сортировки. Функции 3 - алгоритм один. Итого среди указанных функций всего 2 разных алгоритма сортировки (стабильная и нестабильная).

Comment: Вопрос изначально был о другом: что лучше - использовать готовую реализацию алгоритма, или пытаться самостоятельно реализовать какой-то из множества [алгоритмов сортировки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Алгоритм_сортировки), а не какую именно функцию стандартной библиотеки использовать.